# animate border bottom length from 0 to 100

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

i need to animate the border bottom of the div using keyframe animation without using :before or :after or modifying the current html structure

```css
div{
    padding:3px 6px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1></div>
```

Comment: Have you googled "keyframe animation" and try to understand how to use it?

Comment: yes, i have already used it for animating width, left or right, opacity etc. but here i am trying to animate length of border which is not working. i need some help for the same

Comment: Ah, I see now. I thought you wanted to change the width, not the length. I think the first step would be to figure out a way to limit the length of a border, keyframes can be added when you've figured that out

Comment: https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/eNNdme

Comment: @Roy OP asked without `:after`

Answer (score 3):

Use gradient:

```css
div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) bottom/0% 2px no-repeat;
  transition: 1s all;
}

div.box:hover {
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate it like below. Hope that helps.

```css
.container {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.underline {
  height: 2px;
  max-width: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: drawBorder 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes drawBorder {
  from {
    max-width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```